# Resign first responder hides keyboard but does not generate keyboard will hide / keyboard did hide events

Tags: ios4, keyboard-events

I am trying to automate some text field for testing purposes. I programmatically do this

```
[textField becomeFirstResponder]; // Keyboard pops up
[textField setText:@"sometext"];  // Some text is automatically entered into text  field
[textField resignFirstResponder]; // Keyboard goes away
```

The keyboard will show, keyboard did show events are fired up. But when the keyboard goes away it doesn't fire keyboard will hide / keyboard did hide events.

How can I automate these events? Any ideas will be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by adding a custom button to the keyboard. Since I have pointer to that button I just did
[button sendActionsForControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside]

This actually generates keyboard will hide event first.
Then the textfield does an EndEdit event.
Then the keyboard did hide event gets fired.